# Win conditions for Match 3 game

Tags: c++

I have a randomly generated 10x5 array that I want to check when 3 numbers match both horizontally, and vertically. I can't figure out a good way to do the check to see if the numbers match. The way I am currently doing it, it would take me over 70 if statements, and I know there is a better way. I don't think I can use a for loop to check though because I need to know exactly which 3 numbers (and their location) are the same.

Here is the code I have so far, sorry if it is a little long. I only included the check for one row to save space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
int col = 5;
int row = 0;

int board[9][4];
int i;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 srand(time(NULL));

 // generate the random board

 cout << "==========\n";
 while (row < 1)
 {
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
   board[row][i] = rand()%5 + 1;
   cout << board[row][i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "==========\n";
  row++;
 }

 //----check for matches-----

 // row 1
 if (board[0][0] == (board[0][1] && board[0][2]))
 {
  cout << "Balls 1,2,3 match\n";
 }
 if (board[0][2] == (board[0][3] && board[0][4]))
 {
  cout << "Balls 3,4,5 match\n";
 }
 if (board[0][1] == (board[0][2] && board[0][3]))
 {
  cout << "Balls 2,3,4 match\n";
 }
 if (board[0][0] == (board[0][1] && board[0][2] && board[0][3]))
 {
  cout << "Balls 1,2,3,4 match\n";
 }
 if (board[0][1] == (board[0][2] && board[0][3] && board[0][4]))
 {
  cout << "Balls 2,3,4,5 match\n";
 }
 if (board[0][0] == (board[0][1] && board[0][2] && board[0][3] && board[0][4]))
 {
  cout << "Balls 1,2,3,4,5 match\n";
 }
 else
 {
  cout << "No balls match\n";
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Win conditions for a connect-4 like game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636575/win-conditions-for-a-connect-4-like-game)

Comment: That's also my post, but it isn't the same

Comment: How is this question different?

Comment: The basic idea seems to be the same, use a loop or series of loops to replace countless hand written checks. Your first three checks are identical except they add 1 to some values. Turn those values into variables and write a loop to make it run multiple times.

Comment: What does your code do when you run it? I am missing something about your use of &&... or are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I see between this question and your previous question is that you want to know the location and direction of the match.  In that case, here is a minor modification to @templatetypedef's [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636575/win-conditions-for-a-connect-4-like-game/4636632#4636632).

```
enum Direction { NONE, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, DIAGONAL_UP, DIAGONAL_DOWN };

Direction IsLineStartingAt(int x, int y) {
    if (IsLinearMatch(x, y, 1,  0) return HORIZONTAL;
    if (IsLinearMatch(x, y, 0,  1) return VERTICAL;
    if (IsLinearMatch(x, y, 1,  1) return DIAGONAL_DOWN;
    if (IsLinearMatch(x, y, 1, -1) return DIAGONAL_UP;
    return NONE;
}
```

If you run that through a for loop, you already have the x and y starting locations, and this will return the direction, or none if there is no match.

Comment: I need to know the EXACT location of each of the matches not just if they are vertical or horizontal.

Comment: That information can be derived given the location and direction.  If it's horizontal, then the match is ([x][y],[x+1][y],[x+2][y]), if it's vertical, then the match is ([x][y],[x][y+1],[x][y+2]), etc...